# Network programming. Determine end of message

Tags: c++, c, sockets, network-programming, cross-platform

Linux buffers all received messages received on a socket. But before receiving, this messages had a beginning and an end. Linux writes this messages sequentially in the buffer, loosing therefore the information of the end of the message.

I know that in Linux I could use cmsg_header.But Windows does not offer send-/recvmsg() procedures. How do I determine the end of a message on the buffer platformagnostic?

Comment: Which protocol do you use, TCP or UDP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A network facing application typically has a clear transport/business logic separation.

Business layer operates whole messages only. Transport is delivering whole messages to the upstream business layer potentially assembling continuous stream from fragments, re-slicing, and re-interpreting it as a series of messages.

Transport layer is typically communicating with the remote transport layer using protocol messages of form [size(length=S)][payload(variable length)]. Where [size] is a single number whose marshalled length S is known to all communicating parties.

The first thing the transport layer does is it waits to receive S bytes from the downstream (either asynchronously or synchronously, does not matter) into a temporary buffer. Once done it unmarshals received data and becomes aware of the length of the payload to be received L.

Once the lenght of the payload L is known transport is waiting to receive L bytes from the downstream into a temporary buffer (may have to combine multiple reads) and once done it notifies application layer passing it the whole assembled message in a single buffer.

Comment: This is all fantasy. TCP provides a byte stream only. The TCP transport layer has no knowledge whatsoever of application messages or message lengths. There is also nothing here that actually answers the question. If all this was true the OP wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: @EJP - where did I mention _TCP_ in my answer? Must be in your fantasy. In my answer _transport_ is what's used by the message oriented applications to communicate with one other. Abstract thinking does help.

Comment: care to explain 3 more downvotes (apart from the one from EJP's misunderstanding)?

Comment: I have misunderstood nothing. The OP is *asking* about TCP, and about the behaviour of specific Linux system calls. The meaning of 'transport layer' in networking is well established and is not what you state here. Your abstractions don't answer the question.

Comment: @EJP - here is what _transport_ means in English: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_%28disambiguation%29#Scientific_and_technical_uses, I hope you will stop misinterpreting my answer in your further comments and stop arguing about terminology. Another place to look is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985004/using-boost-asio-to-get-the-whole-packet/2985067#2985067 to recall how asynchronous socket IO works (feel free to down vote it as well). This should make you understand that it does look like a sequence of blocks of random size to the client code, not as a stream of data.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure that TCP/IP connections are exchanging well delimited messages. Routers could fragment packets. (So `cmsg_header` could be unreliable).

All TCP/IP based protocols I know about (HTTP, SMTP, X11, RPCXDR) are handling message organization at the application level. Your application library need to know somehow when and when a "message" starts or ends.

Answer (score 4):

Just send in the first 4 bytes the length of the message in network order. Then you will not have this problem.

Comment: ... but beware of endianess issues.

Answer (score 2):

I think the Winsock equivalents of `sendmsg`, `recvmsg` are `WSASendMsg` and `WSARecvMsg`. They take a `LPWSAMSG` argument which is, according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741687%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), a structure based on the Posix.1g specification for the msghdr structure.

Comment: However none of this bears on the question of messages via TCP, which is a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 1):

> Linux writes this messages sequentially in the buffer, loosing therefore the information of the end of the message.

That's not correct. There was never any 'information [about] the end of the message' to lose at the receiving end. TCP is a byte-stream protocol. Your `send()`s or `write()`s got concatenated *at the sender*, into its socket *send* buffer, and from there the data was transmitted in TCP segments and IP packets however the transport decided to do so.

If you want messages over TCP, you have to implement them entirely yourself. Common techniques:

- send a length word ahead of the message
- encapsulate the message, e.g. between STX and ETX, with suitable escaping for ETX (ESC ETX) if it occurs in the message, and therefore with escaping for ESC itself (ESC ESC) when occurring in the message
- use a self-describing protocol such as XML.